# highchart hide xaxis categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

im using [highchart](http://highcharts.com) and I want to hide the xaxis categories (the numbers on the bottom of the chart, please see the below image reference). Does anyone knows how to hide it?

[image]

Comment: For doing this leave the x-axis categories blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: false // disable labels
  }
}
```

[API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.enabled) reference.